# Algorithm for calculating the duplicates in a list

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, duplicates

The code below prints out the numbers which are duplicated in `A`. 
From my understanding, the for loop goes through each element in the list and turns it into a negative number, though i can not figure out why it does not turn the numbers it prints (which are at at position 0,4,5) negative.

```
A = [1,2,3,1,3,6,6]
def printRepeating(arr, size): 

    print("The repeating elements are: ") 

    for i,x in enumerate(arr): 

        if arr[abs(arr[i])] >= 0: 

            arr[abs(arr[i])] = -arr[abs(arr[i])] 
            print(arr)
        else: 
            print (abs(arr[i]), end = " ") 
printRepeating(A,len(A))
```

Comment: Stepping through this code with the help of e.g. [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/) probably help you see what's going on

Comment: This code only changes entries at indexes that are taken from the array itself. Since the array does not have values of 0, 4 and 5, these indexes are never changed. On the other hand, if you put a 7 instead one of those values, you will get out of range. Are you sure that you want to access the array as `arr[abs(arr[i])]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm assumes:

1. all the elements of the array start as positive numbers, and
2. all the elements of the array are less than the length of the array.

In your example, since the length of the array is 7, all the elements in the array must be between 1 and 6.

What the algorithm does is change  `array[k]` to negative to indicate that `k` has been seen. For example, since 1 is the first number seen, `array[1]` is changed to a negative number. The next time 1 is seen, `array[1]` is already negative, so 1 must be a duplicate.

Comment: I was under the impression the for loop would iterate through each element of A once and therefore would not pick up on the changes made. For example elements 1 , 2 ,3 would be turned negative after 3 iterations but this information will not mean anything until a new for loop is made to start the iterations all over again from the first element?

Comment: Notice that the code is using `arr[abs(arr[i])]`, it's not using `arr[i]`. So elements `arr[1]`, `arr[2]` and `arr[3]` are turned negative after 3 iterations.  On the fourth iteration, the code checks `arr[abs(arr[4])]` which is `arr[abs(1)]` which is `arr[1]`. So it's accessing `arr[1]` a second time, and sees that it's negative already. So 1 is a duplicate.

Comment: so effectively it updates the array and then rereads it as it until it reaches the end of the array ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the repeated values in the list then why not try this:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 6, 6]
def get_repeated_elements(lst):
   return list(set((i for i in lst if lst.count(i) > 1)))
print(get_repeated_elements(A))
```

This function converts the passed array into a generator of duplicated values
and then converts this into a set to filter out duplicates in the generator and then converts this into a list for returning to the caller. This is a far shorter function than the one given.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm assumes that all entries are strictly positive and smaller than the length of the list. Then, what it does is essentially using the sign of the `i`-th element to store if it already saw number `i`. In your example:

```
A=[1,2,3,1,3,6,6]  Take 1
A[1] is positive, i.e. we have not seen it. Make it negative to mark it
A=[1,-2,3,1,3,6,6] Take -2  (stands for 2)
A[2] is positive, i.e. we have not seen it. Make it negative to mark it
A=[1,-2,-3,1,3,6,6] Take -3
A[3] is positive, i.e. we have not seen it. Make it negative to mark it
A=[1,-2,-3,-1,3,6,6] Take -1
A[1] is negative, i.e. we have already seen it. Report it.
A=[1,-2,-3,-1,3,6,6] Take 3
A[3] is negative, i.e. we have already seen it. Report it.
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code can be used to find repeated elements in the list and also unique elements in the list.

```
from collections import Counter
A = [1,2,3,1,3,6,6]

B =  Counter(A)
```

The below line prints repeated elements.

```
[k for k, v in B.items() if v > 1]
Output : [1, 3, 6]
```

The below line prints unique elements.

```
[k for k, v in B.items() if v == 1]
Output : [2]
```